# Indefinite Integral Questions

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate the following indefinite integral.

$$ \int \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 36-x^2 } } \,  dx $$

How could i do this integral ?

Comment: I assume you've learned trig substitution?  What substitution would make that radical go away?

Comment: $ so\quad let\quad u\quad =\quad 36-{ x }^{ 2 }\quad \frac { du }{ dx } =-2x\quad du\quad =\quad -2xdx\quad dx=-\frac { du }{ 2x } \quad xdx\quad =\quad -\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \quad du $ Is that right so far ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{36-x^2}} \, dx = \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{36}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{x^2}{36}}}} \, dx = \int \frac{1}{{\sqrt{1-\left(\dfrac{x}{6}\right)^2}}} \, \frac{dx}{6} = \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}} \, du.
$$
That last integral is in all the tables.

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $x=6\sin\theta$, giving $dx=6\cos\theta\, d\theta$. So the integral changes to
$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{36-36\sin^2\theta}}6\cos\theta \, d\theta$$

Now you should be able to do it

If you want to substitute $u=36-x^2$, then $du=-2x \, dx$. Then the integral becomes $\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}\frac{du}{-2x}$. Again you will have to back substitute the value of $x$ in terms of $u$ from the original substitution which is tedious.

Comment: I substituted differently. $ so\quad let\quad u\quad =\quad 36-{ x }^{ 2 }\quad \frac { du }{ dx } =-2x\quad du\quad =\quad -2xdx\quad dx=-\frac { du }{ 2x } \quad xdx\quad =\quad -\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \quad du $ Isn't that right ?

Comment: no.check the answer

Comment: Can you continue your answer with the trig substitution because i still can't continue with what you did.

Comment: @Tennisman note that $1 - \sin^2 \theta = \cos^2 \theta$